# Identify the start and end of a trip in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to identify the duration of an activity that start at t1 and end at t7. The starting point is t1 that records the occurrence of an activity at t1_1 , t1_2, t1_3 and so on. For example in the case of id 12 activity occurred at t1_2 and t1_3 (i would like to save this) t2_2 (as there is no activity before and after I am not intrested in this activity), t3_1 (same as t2_2), t3_3, t4_2, t5_2, t6_1, t6_2, t6_3 and t7_3. I would like to identify to the start and end  all id's in which an activity occured, the duration and the most frequent one.

Input:

```
id t1_1 t1_2 t1_3 t2_1 t2_2 t2_3 t3_1 t3_2 t3_3 t4_1 t4_2 t4_3 t5_1 t5_2 t5_3 t6_1 t6_2 t6_3 t7_1 t7_2 t7_3
12  0    1     1    0     1   0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0     1   1     1   0      0  1
123 0    0     0    1     1   1    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1     0   0     0    1     1  1
 10  1   1     1    1     1    1    1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1   1     1    1     1  1
```

Output for id 12

```
Id    Start/End    Duration  Frequency
12   t1_1, t1_3     2         1
12   t6_1, t6_3     3         1
```

One way to dot this is using the bioconductor library but are there any better solution?

Sample data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(12L, 123L, 10L), t1_1 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), 
            t1_2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t1_3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t2_1 = c(0L, 
            1L, 1L), t2_2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), t2_3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), t3_1 = c(1L, 
            0L, 1L), t3_2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), t3_3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t4_1 = c(0L, 
            1L, 1L), t4_2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), t4_3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), t5_1 = c(0L, 
            1L, 1L), t5_2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), t5_3 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), t6_1 = c(1L, 
            0L, 1L), t6_2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t6_3 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), t7_1 = c(0L, 
            1L, 1L), t7_2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L), t7_3 = c(1L, 1L, 1L)), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
        -3L))
```

Comment: @akrun 123 and 10  should be invluded sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We convert to 'long' format with `pivot_longer`, then create a grouping variable with `rleid` (from `data.table`) based on the occurrence of similar adjacent elements in 'value', `filter` the rows where the 'value' is 1, grouped by 'id', 'grp', we keep only rows where the frequency count is greater than 1, `summarise` by `paste`ing (`str_c`) the `first` and `last` elements of 'name' as well get the count (`n()`) and `arrange` if necessary

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>% 
   mutate(grp = rleid(value)) %>%
   filter(as.logical(value)) %>%
   group_by(id, grp) %>% 
   filter(n() > 1) %>%
   summarise(Start_End = str_c(first(name), last(name), sep=", "),
       Duration = n()) %>%
   arrange(id, grp)
```

Comment: @user10974052 ii added some explanation

Comment: could you please explain what you measure with the grp varaible

Comment: @user10974052 It is to create a grouping index based on the difference in adjacent  'value' ie. if there the 'value' is not equal for the current and previous element, it increments by 1. e.g. `v1(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a'); rleid(v1)` makes sure that the non-adjacent 'a' does not belong to same gorup

Answer (score 1):

```
library('data.table')
df1 <- melt(setDT(df1), id.var = 'id')
df1[, c('time', 'subtime') := tstrsplit(as.character(variable), "_", fixed = TRUE)]
df2 <- df1[, rle(value), by = .(id, time)][lengths > 1 & values == 1, ]
df3 <- df1[df2, on = c('id', 'time')]
df3 <- df3[, .(`Start/End` = paste0(time, '_', c(min(subtime), max(subtime)), collapse = " - "), 
                           Duration = unique(lengths)), 
           by = .(id, time)]
df3[, Frequency := .N, by = .(id, `Start/End`)]
df3[, time := NULL]
df3[order(id), ]

#     id   Start/End Duration Frequency
# 1:  10 t1_1 - t1_3        3         1
# 2:  10 t2_1 - t2_3        3         1
# 3:  10 t3_1 - t3_3        3         1
# 4:  10 t4_1 - t4_3        3         1
# 5:  10 t5_1 - t5_3        3         1
# 6:  10 t6_1 - t6_3        3         1
# 7:  10 t7_1 - t7_3        3         1
# 8:  12 t1_1 - t1_3        2         1
# 9:  12 t6_1 - t6_3        3         1
# 10: 123 t2_1 - t2_3        3         1
# 11: 123 t4_1 - t4_3        3         1
# 12: 123 t5_1 - t5_3        3         1
# 13: 123 t7_1 - t7_3        3         1
```